# How do I find my list of "Save this answer" bookmarks?

Tags: support, profile-page, saves

I see the ability to Save an Answer -- *somewhere*.

[image]

Now, where are the bookmarks of Saved Answers displayed or listed for my account?

I don't see them in Answers, nor anywhere else:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you first navigate to your profile, you're brought to your Activity page. Bookmarks (now "Saves") *used* to be on the left, along with your Answers, Questions, etc. That's moved to the top section, next to Profile, Activity, and Settings:

[image: Image of my profile with the Saves button circled]

When you navigate there, you can find the "For later" section and see all of your recently saved items:

[image: Image of Saves page with For later selected]